# How to view photos from album programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I have used the following code to get images from album.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

and

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];

    // Edited image works great (if you allowed editing)
    //myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    // AND the original image works great
    //myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    // AND do whatever you want with it, (NSDictionary *)info is fine now
    //UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    UIImage *image =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [customImageView setImage:image]; 

    customImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
}
```

But i didn't get any response from device. 
I have gone through all SO answers but its not working for me.
Can anyone please tell me how to get images from the photos album.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `release` statement from `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method. Write it as

```
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release];
```

Comment: I used this code in my project, but when i tapped that button(Take image from Album), it is not showing any sign of loading the album, but when i keep on tapping that button it displays the following error "More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail."